# Jquery/Ajax Post To Update Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, post

Newbie here... I have a small poll and wanted to avoid refreshing the page when the poll is submitted, so I have looked up some examples using Ajax/jQuery to handle this. I'm trying to "debug" my Post.php file which is called via Ajax as follows:

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "Post.php",
  data: datastring,
  success: function()
  {
    alert ("Success");
  }
});
```

Post.php for debugging purposes looks as follows:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

I see the "Success" message signifying that the Post.php file is being called successfully, however I do not see the "Hello World" message displayed. Is it not possible to echo text to the screen in the Post.php file called via Ajax?

Comment: If you ever want to echo text back from the server just so you can debug, but don't want to display it to the user, you can go to (On FireFox/Safari/Chrome) Inspect Element -> Network tab -> Response. This will show you exactly what the server sent back, even if your javascript doesn't use it.

Answer (score 5):

The response body is passed as the first parameter to success function.

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) : A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: **The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter**; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Your code should look like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Post.php",
  data: datastring,
  success: function(data){
    alert (data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will pass the result to your success function as an argument as `function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` where `data` is the parsed data returned, `textStatus` is just the text status, and `jqXHR` is the raw request.

You will probably want to do something with the `data` object. Also, make sure to set the `dataType` to the appropriate value (I use HTML below). Try this:

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "Post.php",
  data: datastring,
  dataType: "html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    alert (data);
  }
});
```

This should alert the content returned by PHP.